# Who are the moderators of Super User?

Tags: support, moderators

Who are the moderators of Super User?
I don't see any moderator presence online right now to close out questions I want closed.

Comment: @joe - you can flag the posts for moderator attention if you'd like them closed quickly.

Comment: yes i did ! but no moderator is online as of now ;)

Comment: if possible give some temporary permission to me  I can close those

Comment: @joe: Just use those flags. The mods will get to them when they can. Remember to use your close votes too.  Give it some time, not everything needs to happen ASAP.

Comment: @joe: I don't think it would be wise for anyone at SO to start handing out temporary mod privileges just to get questions closed more quickly. You have the rep to vote to close; many others on SU do as well. If the community agrees with you, the questions will be closed. If a mod comes online and agrees with you, the questions will be closed. The system and community will take care of itself.

Comment: @joe: The mods will not be handing out "temp moderation rights". With your rep level, you are given the privilege of voting to close. With 10k, you will get to see even more options.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23216/where-are-the-su-moderators

Comment: Moderators are not always online 24/7 and I have only just gotten home. However all the flags have now been handled and cleared.

Comment: @diago - Ha..ha... I didn't expect that and I am not blamed you also . Just i want to know about it ., that all ...

Answer (score 13):

If you want things closed use the flag command to flag them for moderator attention please.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/

Comment: This my friend, is the correct answer.

Comment: I have done that on those three questions, and many others in the past. I think the OP concern was he had done that and they still weren't closed. Maybe he wanted them closed faster. That just my opinion I could be wrong...

Comment: All flags handled. Was offline until about 10 minutes ago. Surprisingly busy night.

Answer (score 7):

https://superuser.com/about

Scroll all the way to the bottom. Look for the diamonds... ♦

Comment: if some moderator is online close 3 questions in super user which is not fit into super user pls

Comment: questions are :69138 69118

Comment: Lets not overlook 69125/my-xbox-died-out-of-warranty-what-should-i-expect-when-contacting-microsoft